# jQuery UI Sortable works strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying around with [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

I have 3 Divs which are invisible at first, but become visible if a button is clicked. The Divs then need to be sortable.

It works somehow, but when I'm dragging a Div over another Div, it doesn't "make place" for it. So the Div underneath has to move away and leave a "gap" for the new Div.
Strangely, it only works, if I remove the CSS, where it is defined, that those Divs are invisible at first.

This is what I have:

```
<style>
.myClass {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_1'>Div 1<div>");
    $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_2'>Div 2<div>");
    $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_3'>Div 3<div>");

    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        makeVisible();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( ".content2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".content2"
        }).disableSelection();
    });

    function makeVisible(){
        $('.myClass').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
</script>
<div class="content1"></div>
<div class="content2"></div>
<button>Visible</button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/5/

---

This is the expected behavior (with the removed CSS):

https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/2/

**Edit:**
I checked it with Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The problem is the inline-block display? Because in the example the elements are inline-block, not block as the second example.

Comment: see this case https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: I edited the 1st fiddle to just `block` instead of `inline-block`, but there is no difference.

Comment: you need vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @Cuchu: Horizontal, that's why I had `inline-block` at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, the placeholder will also have the class `myClass` and hence will be invisible as per your existing CSS. You can fix this by updating your selector to exclude the sortable helper:

```
.myClass:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder) {
  display: none;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder{
  visibility:visible !important;
  border:1px solid black; /*for demo*/
}
```

By default jQuery UI sets the helper visibility to `visibility:hidden` so that it looks like an empty space. If you actuall want to see it, you should override this too.

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/10/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of you are using `display:none` instead use `visibility:hidden;`. Because display property remove the space.

```
.myClass {
    visibility:hidden;
}

function makeVisible(){
        $('.myClass').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
```

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/7/)**

**There is one another solution is:**

Remove class using JQuery on button click

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_1'>Div 1<div>");
 $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_2'>Div 2<div>");
 $('.content2').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_3'>Div 3<div>");
 
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  makeVisible();
 });
 
 $(function() {
  $( ".content2" ).sortable({
   connectWith: ".content2"
  }).disableSelection();
 });
 
 function makeVisible(){
  $('.content2').find('*').removeClass("myClass");
 }
});
```

```css
.myClass {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="content1"></div>
<div class="content2"></div>
<button>Visible</button>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

check this option https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/1nbmkyzp/

```
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <div class="content2"></div>
    <button>Visible</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content2').append('<div class="tab" id="tab1">1</div>');
    $('.content2').append('<div class="tab" id="tab2">2</div>');
    $('.content2').append('<div class="tab" id="tab3">3</div>');

    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        makeVisible();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.content2').sortable({
    containment: 'parent',
    axis: 'x'
});
    });

    function makeVisible(){
        $('.myClass').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
</script>

<style>
.content2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    border: 2px solid #aaf;
    font-size: 0;
}

.tab {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 41px;
    border: 2px solid #faa;
    margin: 0 1px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center;
}

#tab1, #tab5, #tab2, #tab4, #tab3 { width: 35px; }

h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in the function makeVisible, you set display:inline-block

The solution is the following:

```
function makeVisible(){
      $('.myClass').css('display', 'block');
  }
```

[your modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/kka1z1k7/4/)

Comment: There is no difference for me. I checked it with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For me is working without the bad behavior.

I took your example and forked it.

Added the css you deleted, added the button you forget.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5jht6cf/1/

```
<button>button</button>

.myClass {
    display: none;
}
```

Can be the browser?

Also take care about "inline-block" or "block" depending on your needs.

Comment: There is no difference for me. I checked it with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

Added an addition wrapper to help manage the button visible & sortable separately. Then also added a extra bit of CSS to get the div's side by side like in your example.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kka1z1k7/8/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="content1"></div>

 <div class="content2">
    <div class="target"></div>
 </div>

<button>Visible</button>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content2 .target').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_1'>Div 1<div>");
   $('.content2 .target').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_2'>Div 2<div>");
   $('.content2 .target').append("<div class='myClass' id='ro_3'>Div 3<div>");

   $( "button" ).click(function() {
     makeVisible();
   });

   $(function() {
     $( ".target" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".target"
     }).disableSelection();
   });

   function makeVisible(){
    $('.content2').css('display', 'inline-block');
   }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div.myClass {
  float:left;
}
```